# problem with symlink in Hostinger with laravel

Tags: php, laravel, symlink, shared-hosting

i am in Hostinger shared host, and in subdomain..so my Laravel project inside (osamaStartup) folder:

```
username/ domains/ osamamy.com/ public_html/ osamaStartup
```

I really tried everything, like using a PHP file to make a symlink, but it give me an error message that the symlink function is not defined...

also, I have tried to make a link using the command (ln -s) but it doesn't work:

```
ln -s ../storage/app/public/ storage/
```

.... hope anyone here can solve this problem.... thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after one year of suffering from Hostinger, finally, I just upgrade to Business shared hosting, and now everything working well .... this command is run successfully :

```
PHP artisan storage:link
```