# How to access images outside public_html folder in Shared Hosting or create a shorcut using symlink inside public_html folder (Hostinger)

Tags: php, laravel, shared-hosting, laravel-9

I tried to create a shorcut folder inside my public_html folder using the command

```
ln -s LaravelApp/storage/app/public/images public_html/storage"
```

but it says invalid link.

[Here is the image: This is inside my public_html folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GFFBE.png)

The only one that worked was when I created a shorcut outside the public_html folder but the thing is I cannot access it because it is outside the public_html folder. Is there a way to access the shorcut despite being outside the public folder or a way to create a shorcut inside the public folder? By the way I am using hostinger. Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19979537/how-can-i-show-the-images-outside-the-web-root-directory-in-my-php-application

Comment: There is existing Q&A on site and it can depend on different things on _Hostinger_ - none of which you have shared in your question so far. Please refer to the existing solutions and then [edit] in all the details.

Comment: Some user reported changing plans helped them: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72448243/367456